# probability that your vote tips the election results

Tags: probability, random-variables

$\textbf{Question:}$

Assume a presidential elections with two candidates $A$ and $B$ and $2n+1$ voters. Assume that each voter will choose $A$ with probability $p$ and $B$ with probability $1-p$. Let the random variables $X$ and $Y$ denote the number of votes that go to $A$ and $B$ respectively.

$\textbf{a)}$ Find the distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

$\textbf{b)}$ Assume that $2n$ out of $2n+1$ have already voted. Let $T$ be the event that the vote of $2n+1$-st person is a tie-breaker. Describe $T$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$.

$\textbf{c)}$ Compute $\mathbb{P}(T)$.

$\textbf{Comments:}$

I (think) solved part $a)$ and I got $$F_X(k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\dbinom{2n+1}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$ if $0 \leq k \leq 2n+1$ and $0$ otherwise. Similarly $$F_Y(k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\dbinom{2n+1}{i}(1-p)^ip^{n-i}$$ if $0 \leq k \leq 2n+1$ and $0$ otherwise.

And part $c)$ $\mathbb{P}(T)=\frac{\dbinom{2n}{n}}{p^n(1-p)^n}$, but I can't figure out how to solve part $b)$. Since both $X$ and $Y$ denote number of votes of $A$ and $B$ respectively but from $2n+1$ voters I dont know how to relate this to the event that $2n$ voters voted and its the results is so far a tie. I though of of this :

$T=\frac{1}{2}(pf_X(n)+(1-p)f_Y(n))$ but I don't know whether it makes much sense or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to have been posed very strangely.  Clearly we have $Y=2n+1-X$.

Given $X=n+1$ (so $Y=n$), the final vote is a tie-breaker if it voted for A, and it does that with conditional probability $\dfrac{n+1}{2n+1}$

Given $X=n$ (so $Y=n+1$), the final vote is a tie-breaker if it voted for B, and it does that with conditional probability $\dfrac{n+1}{2n+1}$

That then gives $$\Pr(T)=  \dfrac{n+1}{2n+1}\dbinom{2n+1}{n+1}p^{n+1}(1-p)^{n} + \dfrac{n+1}{2n+1}\dbinom{2n+1}{n}p^{n}(1-p)^{n+1}$$ which simplifies to what you intended to write: $\Pr(T)= \dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n}(1-p)^{n}$

Comment: why is the conditional probability $\frac{n+1}{2n+1}$?

Comment: If there are $n+1$ of one type and $n$ of the other making a total of $2n+1$, the probability that the last was a tie-breaker is the probability it was in the $n+1$ group which is $\frac{n+1}{2n+1}$

Answer (score 0):

Question (b) has no solution. If the last vote is a tie breaker, then either $X=Y+1$ or $Y=X+1$. Or more succinctly, $Y=X\pm1$. But these requirements do not imply that the last vote was a tie breaker, for the state of the vote before the last vote was cast could be $Y'=X'\pm2$. (Here $X'$, $Y'$ are the vote tallies after $2n$ votes.)